# How to simplify creating a deeply nested hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, optimization, hash

I currently have:

```
@teams ||= {}
@teams[date] ||= {}
@teams[date][team] ||= {}
@teams[date][team][raw_address] ||= {}
@teams[date][team][raw_address]['address'] = address
@teams[date][team][raw_address]['orders'] ||= {}
@teams[date][team][raw_address]['orders'][order.id] = order
```

Is it possible to "remove" the lines containing `||= {}`? I just want to have something like:

```
@teams[date][team][raw_address]['address'] = address
@teams[date][team][raw_address]['orders'][order.id] = order
```

Answer (score 5):

You might know that in Ruby, hashes can have [default values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Default+Values).

So when initially creating the `@team` hash, you could set a default value of e.g. *empty hash*:

```
@team = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new }
```

Which gives you:

```
@team[:foo] #=> {}
```

And the ability to set values in those dynamically created hashes, e.g.:

```
@team[:foo][:bar] = 123
@team[:foo][:baz] = 456

@team
#=> {
#     :foo => {
#       :bar => 123,
#       :baz => 456
#     }
#   }
```

But that only works for the first level. To get a hash that can be nested *indefinitely*, you have to pass along the outer hash's [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#default_proc-method) to the inner hash:

```
@team = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

Doing so allows you to create deeply nested hashes by just assigning the last element, e.g.:

```
@team[:foo][:bar][:baz] = 123
@team[:foo][:bar][:qux][:quux] = 456

@team
#=> {
#     :foo=> {
#       :bar => {
#         :baz => 123,
#         :qux => {
#           :quux => 456
#         }
#       }
#     }
#   }
```